# Join two data frames, select all columns from one and some columns from the other

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a spark data frame `df1`, with several columns (among which the column `id`) and data frame `df2` with two columns, `id` and `other`.

Is there a way to replicate the following command:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT df1.*, df2.other FROM df1 JOIN df2 ON df1.id = df2.id")
```

by using only pyspark functions such as `join()`, `select()` and the like?

I have to implement this join in a function and I don't want to be forced to have sqlContext as a function parameter.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Not sure if the most efficient way, but this worked for me:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df1.alias('a').join(df2.alias('b'),col('b.id') == col('a.id')).select([col('a.'+xx) for xx in a.columns] + [col('b.other1'),col('b.other2')])
```

The trick is in:

```
[col('a.'+xx) for xx in a.columns] : all columns in a

[col('b.other1'),col('b.other2')] : some columns of b
```

Comment: In spark2, I had to change this to col('b.id') == col('a.id')  (with two equals signs). Otherwise, it gives me a 'SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression' exception

Comment: Hi, How can I pass multiple columns as a list instead of individual cols like this [col('b.other1'),col('b.other2')] for df2 dataset

Answer (score 120):

Asterisk (`*`) works with alias. Ex:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1 = df1.alias('df1')
df2 = df2.alias('df2')

df1.join(df2, df1.id == df2.id).select('df1.*')
```

Comment: perfect -- full solution;      { df1.join(df2, df1.id == df2.id).select('df1.*', 'df2.other') }

Comment: You wrote `df1 = df1.alias('df1')` and `df2 = df2.alias('df2')`. What is the purpose here? You are renaming `df1` as `df1`. Isn't this useless?

Comment: @Sheldore see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46358218/1552998

Comment: Somehow this approach doesn't work on Spark 3 for me.

Answer (score 86):

**Without using alias.**

```
df1.join(df2, df1.id == df2.id).select(df1["*"],df2["other"])
```

Comment: I notice that when joined dataframes have same-named column names, doing `df1["*"]` in the select method correctly gets the columns from that dataframe even if `df2` had columns with some of the same names as `df1`. Would you mind explaining (or linking to docs on) how this works?

Comment: This is the current (2022) best answer IMHO

Answer (score 13):

Here is a solution that does not require a SQL context, but maintains the metadata of a DataFrame.

```
a = sc.parallelize([['a', 'foo'], ['b', 'hem'], ['c', 'haw']]).toDF(['a_id', 'extra'])
b = sc.parallelize([['p1', 'a'], ['p2', 'b'], ['p3', 'c']]).toDF(["other", "b_id"])
    
c = a.join(b, a.a_id == b.b_id).select(a["*"],b["other"])
```

Then, `c.show()` yields:

```
+----+-----+-----+
|a_id|extra|other|
+----+-----+-----+
|   a|  foo|   p1|
|   b|  hem|   p2|
|   c|  haw|   p3|
+----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Well, the OP has asked for selection of only few cols, ie. filteration, the answer has all the columns after join.

Comment: Please modify your answer to include the missing ```select()``` to include only required columns after ```join()```

Answer (score 9):

I believe that this would be the easiest and most intuitive way:

```
final = (df1.alias('df1').join(df2.alias('df2'),
                               on = df1['id'] == df2['id'],
                               how = 'inner')
                         .select('df1.*',
                                 'df2.other')
)
```

Answer (score 5):

drop duplicate b_id

```
c = a.join(b, a.a_id == b.b_id).drop(b.b_id)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code snippet that does the inner join and select the columns from both dataframe and alias the same column to different column name.

```
emp_df  = spark.read.csv('Employees.csv', header =True);
dept_df = spark.read.csv('dept.csv', header =True)


emp_dept_df = emp_df.join(dept_df,'DeptID').select(emp_df['*'], dept_df['Name'].alias('DName'))
emp_df.show()
dept_df.show()
emp_dept_df.show()
```

```
Output  for 'emp_df.show()':

+---+---------+------+------+
| ID|     Name|Salary|DeptID|
+---+---------+------+------+
|  1|     John| 20000|     1|
|  2|    Rohit| 15000|     2|
|  3|    Parth| 14600|     3|
|  4|  Rishabh| 20500|     1|
|  5|    Daisy| 34000|     2|
|  6|    Annie| 23000|     1|
|  7| Sushmita| 50000|     3|
|  8| Kaivalya| 20000|     1|
|  9|    Varun| 70000|     3|
| 10|Shambhavi| 21500|     2|
| 11|  Johnson| 25500|     3|
| 12|     Riya| 17000|     2|
| 13|    Krish| 17000|     1|
| 14| Akanksha| 20000|     2|
| 15|   Rutuja| 21000|     3|
+---+---------+------+------+

Output  for 'dept_df.show()':
+------+----------+
|DeptID|      Name|
+------+----------+
|     1|     Sales|
|     2|Accounting|
|     3| Marketing|
+------+----------+

Join Output:
+---+---------+------+------+----------+
| ID|     Name|Salary|DeptID|     DName|
+---+---------+------+------+----------+
|  1|     John| 20000|     1|     Sales|
|  2|    Rohit| 15000|     2|Accounting|
|  3|    Parth| 14600|     3| Marketing|
|  4|  Rishabh| 20500|     1|     Sales|
|  5|    Daisy| 34000|     2|Accounting|
|  6|    Annie| 23000|     1|     Sales|
|  7| Sushmita| 50000|     3| Marketing|
|  8| Kaivalya| 20000|     1|     Sales|
|  9|    Varun| 70000|     3| Marketing|
| 10|Shambhavi| 21500|     2|Accounting|
| 11|  Johnson| 25500|     3| Marketing|
| 12|     Riya| 17000|     2|Accounting|
| 13|    Krish| 17000|     1|     Sales|
| 14| Akanksha| 20000|     2|Accounting|
| 15|   Rutuja| 21000|     3| Marketing|
+---+---------+------+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I got an error: 'a not found' using the suggested code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col df1.alias('a').join(df2.alias('b'),col('b.id') == col('a.id')).select([col('a.'+xx) for xx in a.columns] + [col('b.other1'),col('b.other2')])
```

I changed `a.columns` to `df1.columns` and it worked out.

Comment: Changing the name of the variable should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

### function to drop duplicate columns after joining.

## check it

def dropDupeDfCols(df):
    newcols = []
    dupcols = []

```
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    if df.columns[i] not in newcols:
        newcols.append(df.columns[i])
    else:
        dupcols.append(i)

df = df.toDF(*[str(i) for i in range(len(df.columns))])
for dupcol in dupcols:
    df = df.drop(str(dupcol))

return df.toDF(*newcols)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers mentioned above I got ambiguous column exception (this happens when two dataframes have same column, Also I am using spark on databricks). I tried this and it worked.

```
df_join = df1.join(df2, (df1.a == df2.a) & (df1.b == df2.b), "inner").select(df1.columns,df2.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just dropped the columns I didn't need from df2 and joined:

```py
sliced_df = df2.select(columns_of_interest)
df1.join(sliced_df, on=['id'], how='left')
**id should be in `columns_of_interest` tho
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.join(df2, ['id']).drop(df2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need multiple columns from other pyspark dataframe then you can use this

based on single join condition

```
x.join(y, x.id == y.id,"left").select(x["*"],y["col1"],y["col2"],y["col3"])
```

based on multiple join condition

```
x.join(y, (x.id == y.id) & (x.no == y.no),"left").select(x["*"],y["col1"],y["col2"],y["col3"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I very much like Xehron's answer above, and I suspect it's mechanically identical to my solution.  This works in databricks, and presumably works in a typical spark environment (replacing keyword "spark" with "sqlcontext"):

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('t1') #temp table t1
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('t2') #temp table t2

output = (
          spark.sql("""
                    select
                      t1.*
                      ,t2.desired_field(s)
                    from 
                      t1
                    left (or inner) join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
                    """
                   )
          )
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just make the join and after that select the wanted columns https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe%20join#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join

Comment: My question is exactly how to select all columns from one data frame (without enumerating them one by one) and one column from the other