# pyspark left outer join with multiple columns

Tags: join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Pyspark 2.1.0.

I'm attempting to perform a left outer join of two dataframes using the following:
I have 2 dataframes, schema of which appear as follows:

```
crimes
 |-- CRIME_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- YEAR_MTH: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CRIME_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CURRENT_OUTCOME: string (nullable = true)

outcomes
 |-- CRIME_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- YEAR_MTH: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FINAL_OUTCOME: string (nullable = true)
```

I need to be able to join crimes to outcomes based on a left outer since many outcomes exist for a single crime. I would like to exclude columns that are common to both dataframes.

I have tried the following 2 ways, but each generate various errors:

```
cr_outs = crimes.join(outcomes, crimes.CRIME_ID == outcomes.CRIME_ID, 'left_outer')\
 .select(['crimes.'+c for c in crimes.columns] + ['outcomes.FINAL_OUTCOME'])

 from pyspark.sql.functions as fn    
 cr_outs = crimes.alias('a').join(outcomes.alias('b'), fn.col('b.CRIME_ID') = fn.col('a.CRIME_ID') ,'left_outer')\
  .select([fn.col('a.'+ c) for c in a.columns] + b.FINAL_OUTCOME)
```

could anybody suggest an alternative way?
thanks

Comment: wouldn't you also want to include `YEAR_MTH` column on the join? (connecting the ...)

Comment: the one to many relationship is based on CRIME_ID only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick, seems you have to use an alias, similar what has been [posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36132322/join-two-data-frames-select-all-columns-from-one-and-some-columns-from-the-othe), slightly simpler though in PySpark 2.1.0.

```
cr_outs = crimes.alias('a')\
  .join(outcomes, crimes.CRIME_ID == outcomes.CRIME_ID, 'left_outer')\
  .select(*[col('a.'+c) for c in crimes.columns] 
          + [outcomes.FINAL_OUTCOME])

cr_outs.show()
cr_outs.printSchema()

--------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|            CRIME_ID|YEAR_MTH|         REPORTED_BY|        FALLS_WITHIN|LONGITUDE| LATITUDE|            LOCATION|LSOA_CODE|          LSOA_NAME|          CRIME_TYPE|     CURRENT_OUTCOME|       FINAL_OUTCOME|
+--------------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+---------+--------------------+---------+-------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|426085c2ed33af598...| 2017-01|City of London Po...|City of London Po...|-0.086051| 51.51357|On or near Finch ...|E01032739|City of London 001F|         Other theft|Investigation com...|Investigation com...|
|33a3ddb8160a854a4...| 2017-01|City of London Po...|City of London Po...|-0.077777|51.518047|On or near Sandy'...|E01032
..
..
..
root
 |-- CRIME_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- YEAR_MTH: string (nullable = true)
 |-- REPORTED_BY: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FALLS_WITHIN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LONGITUDE: float (nullable = true)
 |-- LATITUDE: float (nullable = true)
 |-- LOCATION: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LSOA_CODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- LSOA_NAME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CRIME_TYPE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CURRENT_OUTCOME: string (nullable = true)
 |-- FINAL_OUTCOME: string (nullable = true)
```

As you can see, there are many more columns than my original post, but no duplicate columns and no renaming of columns either :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can rename temporarily the common columns to remove ambiguity

```
crimes = crimes\
.withColumnRenamed('CRIME_ID','CRIME_ID_1')\
.withColumnRenamed('YEAR_MTH','YEAR_MTH_1)


required_columns = [c for c in crimes.columns] + ['FINAL_OUTCOME']

cr_outs = crimes\
.join(outcomes, crimes.CRIME_ID_1 == outcomes.CRIME_ID, 'left_outer')\
.select(required_columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can drop duplicates using the below function.

```
def dropDupeDfCols(df):
   newcols = []
   dupcols = []

for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    if df.columns[i] not in newcols:
        newcols.append(df.columns[i])
    else:
        dupcols.append(i)

df = df.toDF(*[str(i) for i in range(len(df.columns))])
for dupcol in dupcols:
    df = df.drop(str(dupcol))

return df.toDF(*newcols)## Heading ##
```